# Conditional Probability from textbook example unclear

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am reading "Mathematical Statistics with Applications", 7th edition from Wackerly, Mendelhall and Scheaffer.

On example 2.23 on page 71, it is unclear how they calculate P(A|B).

> Example 2.23: An electronic fuse is produced by five production lines in a manufacturing operation.
> The fuses are costly, are quite reliable, and are shipped to suppliers in 100-unit lots.
> Because testing is destructive, most buyers of the fuses test only a small number of
> fuses before deciding to accept or reject lots of incoming fuses.
> All five production lines produce fuses at the same rate and normally produce
> only 2% defective fuses, which are dispersed randomly in the output. Unfortunately,
> production line 1 suffered mechanical difficulty and produced 5% defectives during
> the month of March. This situation became known to the manufacturer after the fuses
> had been shipped. A customer received a lot produced in March and tested three fuses.
> One failed. What is the probability that the lot was produced on line 1? What is the
> probability that the lot came from one of the four other lines?

Solution: Let B denote the event that a fuse was drawn from line 1 and let A denote the event
that a fuse was defective. Then it follows directly that

$P(B) = 0.2$ and $P(A|B) = 3(.05)(.95)^2 = .135375$

$P(B)$ is clear, because it is one of the 5 production lines.

But I'm not sure how they arrive at this result with $P(A|B)$. Anyone can explain how this is computed?

Comment: In this context, $\Pr(A|B)$ denotes "the probability that one out of three fuses was defective given the fuse came from line 1". Can you take it from here?

Comment: @sudeep5221 I can understand the 3, meaning the 3 fuses, and the 0.05 which I understand should be the probability of an item being defective from line 1. But 0.95^2 isn't clear

Comment: You also want the other two fuses to *not* be defective since you want *exactly one* to be defective.

Comment: @sudeep5221 I see, that helps. 0.95 then is the chance that one of the 2 fuses are not defective. 2 fuses, so 0.95^2. So is it correct then that P(A|B) was not calculated through the P(A|B) = P(A,B)/P(B) formula?

Comment: Yeah. It was computed more through the understanding of what it means, which is what I had explained in my first comment.

Comment: **NB**:  The $3$ is the count of *distinct arrangements for exactly **one** defective among the sample of **three** fuses*.  This is the *binomial coefficient* in the probability mass function for a **Binomial Distribution**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your notation:

$P(B|A) = P(A,B) / P(A)$
$= P(A,B) / (P(A,B)+P(A,B’))$

where $B’$ is the event that the sample was *not* chosen from line 1.

One test failed while two succeeded. The failure might equally have been any one of the three tests. Therefore:

$P(A,B) = 0.2 * 3 * 0.05 * 0.95^2$
$P(A,B’) = 0.8 * 3 * 0.02 * 0.98^2$

$P(B|A) = (5 * 95^2) $
$/ (5 * 95^2 + 8 * 98^2)$

$= 45125 / 121957 = 0.37$ approximately

This value is higher than the prior chance of line 1 being selected $(0.2)$ but is still far from being convincing. It is a plausible result though so our arithmetic may be accurate!